# How do I get the value of a datalist option and assign it to another element?

Tags: javascript

Nothing I try works.

```js
document.getElementById("color-test").value = document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor;
```

```html
<div id="test">Pick a color for the background of this element</div>

<input list="color-test" type="color">
<datalist id="color-test">
  <option value="#ff0000">
  <option value="#0000ff">
  <option value="#008000">
</datalist>
```

First I tried this, which seemed logical to me. Just target the value of the datalist, and assign it to the background color of another element.

It doesn't work. I don't know why.

```js
function validatecolor() {
 document.getElementById("color-test").value =  document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Pick a color for the background of this element</div>

<input list="color-test" type="color">
<datalist id="color-test">
  <option value="#ff0000">
  <option value="#0000ff">
  <option value="#008000">
</datalist>
<button onclick="validatecolor()">Color</button>
```

Then I tried this, the second most logical way of doing it. Put the code inside a function, and use a function caller to trigger it.

This too does not work. I don't know why.

I tried targeting the input with an ID, it doesn't work.
I tried targeting the option itself, it doesn't work.
I tried assigning the datalist value to the innerHTML of the other element instead, just to see if the string will get changed. It doesn't. I don't know why. So, that means that the value itself is not getting captured.

Can anybody walk me through this, and explain why this code doesn't work, and how do I make it work?

I read the similar questions, but they all ask about getting a text value of a datalist, and not assigning it later to something else. I tried some of their solutions, but they don't work, or were too complicated. I just want to know why my simple code is not working.

Comment: A `<datalist>` is a **set** of values - it doesn't have a single "value" of its own.

Comment: You can get all `<option>` elements in a `<datalist>` by doing `Array.from(  document.querySelectorAll( 'datalist > option[value]' ) ).map( el => { name: el.label || el.value, value: el.value } )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct:

1. You are doing the **assignment** in the **wrong direction**. It should be: `elementBackground = valueOfColor`
2. You have to **get** the **value** **of** the **input** field (not the datalist). It should be: `inputfield.value`

This is working:

```js
function validatecolor() {
  document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = document.querySelector("input[list=color-test]").value;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Pick a color for the background of this element</div>

<input list="color-test" type="color">
<datalist id="color-test">
    <option value="#ff0000">
    <option value="#0000ff">
    <option value="#008000">
</datalist>
<button onclick="validatecolor()">Color</button>
```

@Joe No need to change the HTML ;)

Comment: You're right. It works now. The book I bought for learning JS is just progressing too slowly, and not getting into much details. As soon as I learn something, I start testing and experimenting with it, and I keep running into these type of issues. Thanks.

Comment: You're very much welcome :) I learned a lot from here: https://www.youtube.com/c/TheCodingTrain 
I want to add: the best way to learn something like programming is to try and error :D So you are on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ID to the list input and get the value from that. You're currently targeting the `datalist` element. It's not a `select` field so it doesn't work the same way.

```js
function validatecolor() {
 const value = document.getElementById("color").value;
 const el = document.getElementById("test");
 console.log(value);
 el.style.backgroundColor = value;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Pick a color for the background of this element</div>

<input list="color-test" type="color" id="color">
<datalist id="color-test">
  <option value="#ff0000">
  <option value="#0000ff">
  <option value="#008000">
</datalist>
<button onclick="validatecolor()">Color</button>
```

You can also do it as an `onchange` event to avoid having to click the button:

```
const list = document.getElementById("color");

function validatecolor() {
 const value = list.value;
 const el = document.getElementById("test");
 console.log(value);
 el.style.backgroundColor = value;
}

list.addEventListener('change', validatecolor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function validatecolor() {
 document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor =  document.getElementById("color").value;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Pick a color for the background of this element</div>

<input list="colors" type="color", id="color">
<datalist id="colors">
  <option value="#ff0000">
  <option value="#0000ff">
  <option value="#008000">
</datalist>
<button onclick="validatecolor()">Color</button>
```